# number of partitions for global state store in kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is global state store in kafka always one partition or we can have multiple partitions for global  state store changelog topic?

I am not able to find any clear documentation around this.

Comment: Would you mind to create a Jira ticket for it so we can improve our docs? If maybe even better, directly open a PR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Matthias J. Sax has written [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/issues/322#issuecomment-594316485):

> A global store is a read-only materialized view of the data from the corresponding input topic

So it is not like **standard** Kafka Streams changelog topics. Number of partitions is up to the topic creator and Kafka Broker limitation.

Summarizing it doesn't have to be one partition and can be more.

Answer (score 0):

It is more than one. I think the number of partitions is the maximum number of partitions that any of the input topics has (but I am not quite sure).

Comment: It is what you define. Can we have more than one? I think yes, but was not too sure - hence the question.

Comment: A global-KTable can only read from a single topic...